# Solving a differential equation in distribution/generalised functions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I am stuck trying to solve the following differential equation in terms of distribution (theory).

$$x\frac{du}{dx} - \lambda u = 0.$$

This is just for $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.

I know the regular distribution corresponding to the function $f(x) = Ax^{\lambda}$ is a solution but the solution says that $c\delta$ is also a solution for some $c \in \mathbb{C}$ and I am not sure I can see how to derive this.

Answer (score 3):

You have to rewrite the equation itself in terms of distributions. You get then $x\frac{du}{dx}(\phi(x))=\lambda u(\phi(x))$. If $u$ is a distribution then $x\frac{du}{dx}(\phi(x))= -u((x\phi(x))^{'})$. So You have then $-u(x\phi^{'}(x)+\phi(x))=\lambda u(\phi(x))$. This equation is satisfied for $u=\delta$ distribution and $\lambda=-1$.
See also here:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html

Comment: I don't think this explains how one would _find_ the solution involving $\delta$, only how to _verify_ it.

Comment: Correct. I must admit that I don't know how to look for solutions in terms of distributions.

Comment: I think it's not trivial to give a prescription in terms of familiar methods... So, in fact, the question is not routine at all, I think. Usual differential equations courses only refer to "classical" functions, not "generalized" (a.k.a. "distributions"). In two variables, e.g., the "differential equation" (without any actualy derivatives) $(x^2+y^2)u=0$ has infinitely-many linearly independent solutions in distributions...

Answer (score 3):

The equation is
$$xu'-\lambda u = 0,$$
hence
$$(xu)'-(\lambda+1) u = 0$$

If $\lambda =-1$, then the equation becomes $(xu)' = 0$, which then becomes  $xu=c$ ($c$ is a constant). The latter equation has a solution $u = c\cdot pv (1/x) + c_1 \delta_0$ (this equation should be discussed in your textbook; it was also discussed on this site).

If on the other hand $\lambda \ne -1$, you can employ the usual techniques to solve this equation (eulerian chaange of variables $x=e^t$, for example).